# Dynamic creation of custom components

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am trying to dynamically create instances of a custom component I created. The correct way, I assume, is using `new Element.tag('custom-component');`, but this yields the following stacktrace for me:

```
method not found: 'constructor' on null
  my_component_test.dart.browser_test.dart.js 21834:17  J.$index$asx
  my_component_test.dart.browser_test.dart.js 22460:14  <fn>
  unparsed                                              my_component_test.dart.browser_test.dart.js 22583:42  Isolate.prototype.(anonymous function)
  my_component_test.dart.browser_test.dart.js 16549:24  dart._setUpPropertyChanged
  my_component_test.dart.browser_test.dart.js 16521:28  $async$initPolymer
  my_component_test.dart.browser_test.dart.js 3319:13   _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure._captured_protected_1
  my_component_test.dart.browser_test.dart.js 4292:14   _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.dart._wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$1
  my_component_test.dart.browser_test.dart.js 5945:18   dart._rootRunUnary
  my_component_test.dart.browser_test.dart.js 8620:41   _CustomZone.dart._CustomZone.runUnary$2
  my_component_test.dart.browser_test.dart.js 6906:80   _Future__propagateToListeners_handleValueCallback.dart._Future__propagateToListeners_handleValueCallback.call$0
```

However, using `Element.html('<custom-component></custom-component')` with an overwritten empty `TreeSanitizer`, as described here http://japhr.blogspot.de/2013/11/dynamically-generating-polymerdart.html, everything works fine and the tests pass:

```
class NullTreeSanitizer implements NodeTreeSanitizer {
  void sanitizeTree(node) {}
}
componentUnderTest = new Element.html('<my-component></my-component>', treeSanitizer: new NullTreeSanitizer());
```

What could be the problem in my setup? The component seems to be implemented and registered correctly as it works if I disable the checks.

Comment: Can you please add the code of your component and your main method. The question is about Polymer 1.0?

Comment: Is this also in Firefox or is this in Dartium?

Comment: I am using polymer 1.0.0-rc.6. It happens in latest Chrome on Linux. The code is available in this repo: https://github.com/flash1293/polymer_dart_example/tree/darttest

Comment: I also suggest to add `^` before each dependency version, then you get the latest available version up to the next "level". See https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies.html#caret-syntax I had to modify pubspec.yaml to be able to install the dependencies because the versions you defined are not all compatible with my Dart version (1.14 bleeding edge). For production it may make sense to have tight versions constraints though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce the error message when I run the tests without `pub serve`.

run from the directory with the `pubspec.yaml` file

```
pub serve test
```

(it should print that it listens on port 8080)
Then run the tests

```
pub run test -pdartium --pub-serve=8080
```

Comment: Uh, I did run the tests with pub serve but I think I mismatched the ports. I will test it when I get to it and report back.